# Powershell Start-Process - can I make it leave the windows open?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, adobe-after-effects

I'm launching multiple copies of aerender.exe (a command line renderer for Adobe After Effects) using start-process. This renderer produces a truckload of verbiage which is handy to have in order to spot render problems. So rather than use -NonNewWindow I have them all run in separate windows.

Trouble is that if something goes wrong (as it often does) the process quits and the window disappears and I don't know about it unless I go and actually read all the log files #TooMuchLikeWork.

Is there a way of starting a process and leaving the window open after the process quits so I can quickly spot when a render has barfed overnight?

Comment: How are you using Start-Process exactly? In a ps1 script?

Comment: I'm typing into a console emulator (conEmu to be exact).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739322/how-to-keep-the-shell-window-open-after-running-a-powershell-script

**One-time Fix:** Run your script from the PowerShell Console, or launch the PowerShell process using the -NoExit switch. e.g. PowerShell -NoExit "C:\SomeFolder\SomeScript.ps1"

**Per-script Fix:** Add a prompt for input to the end of your script file. e.g. Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

**Global Fix:** Change your registry key to always leave the PowerShell Console window open after the script finishes running.